# deleting values from elm model

Tags: functional-programming, single-page-application, elm

I have successfully implemented a delete player method for the [elm tutorial](https://www.elm-tutorial.org/en/).
However I cannot get the model to update without manually sending a `ForchFetch` msg (via clicking a button) that gets the players from the server again. This is my code:

My delete button:

```
deleteBtn : Player -> Html.Html Msg
deleteBtn player =
    let
        message =
            Msgs.Delete player
    in
       a
            [ class "btn regular", onClick message]
            [ i [ class "fa fa-pencil mr1" ] [], text "Delete" ]
```

My delete messages:

```
type Msg = 
    | Delete Player
    | OnDeletePlayer (Result Http.Error Player) 
    | ForceFetch
    | OnFetchPlayers (WebData (List Player))
```

My update function:

```
update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
        Msgs.ForceFetch ->
          (model, fetchPlayers)
        Msgs.OnFetchPlayers response -> 
        ( { model | players = response }, Cmd.none )
        Msgs.Delete player ->
          (model, deletePlayerCmd player)

        Msgs.OnDeletePlayer (Ok player) ->
          (updateDeletedPlayerList model player, Cmd.none)

        Msgs.OnDeletePlayer (Err player) ->
          (model, Cmd.none)

updateDeletedPlayerList : Model -> Player -> Model 
updateDeletedPlayerList model deletedPlayer =     
     let
         updatedPlayers = RemoteData.map (List.filter (\p -> deletedPlayer /= p)) model.players
     in
         { model | players = updatedPlayers}

deletePlayerCmd : Player -> Cmd Msg
deletePlayerCmd player =
      Http.send Msgs.OnDeletePlayer (deletePlayerRequest player)

deletePlayerRequest : Player -> Http.Request Player
deletePlayerRequest player =
 Http.request
        { body = Http.emptyBody
        , expect = Http.expectJson playerDecoder
        , headers = []
        , method = "DELETE"
        , timeout = Nothing
        , url = savePlayerUrl player.id
        , withCredentials = False
        }
fetchPlayers : Cmd Msg
fetchPlayers =
    Http.get fetchPlayersUrl playersDecoder 
        |> RemoteData.sendRequest 
        |> Cmd.map Msgs.OnFetchPlayers
```

And for good measure my model:

```
type alias Model =
    { players : WebData (List Player)
    , route : Route
    , newPlayerName : String
    , newPlayerId : String
    , newPlayerLevel : Int
    }
```

Edit:

I have tried incorporating `fetchPlayers` in the following manner with no success:

```
Msgs.OnDeletePlayer (Ok player) ->
          (updateDeletedPlayerList model player, fetchPlayers)
```

Comment: If `ForceFetch` works, I don't see why your attempt in your edit doesn't work. Are you sure the the response ends up being `Ok` and not `Err`?

Comment: I solved it, I'll update the answer shortly.

Comment: If you are comparing player records in the filter they might not match as what you get from the server could be different. Better do a comparison for just the player.id.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the model in your code if you don't want to fetch it after deleting, so where you have:

```
Msgs.Delete player ->
          (model, deletePlayerCmd player)
```

you need to change 'model' to a function that will remove the player from it:

```
    Msgs.Delete player ->
        (removePlayer player model, deletePlayerCmd player)

...
removePlayer : Player -> Model -> Model
...
```